# machine learning libraries in C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning

Are there any machine learning libraries in C#? I'm after something like [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/).
Thank you.

Comment: I disagree that this is not a constructive question. I think it's very useful to have a set of user-curated library suggestions over the automated results a google search turns up. I don't see why library suggestions can't be accompanied by "facts, references, and specific expertise" as described in the close notes.

Comment: ANYONE LOOKING FOR FRAMEWORKS: The below answers are dated because the question is locked. There is a popular, open-source C# machine learning framework called Accord.NET and here is its webpage: http://accord-framework.net/

Comment: Also check out http://scisharpstack.org, an effort to port the most popular machine learning libraries from Python to C#

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Check out [this awesome list](https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet#machine-learning-and-data-science) on GitHub. Of the frameworks listed, `Accord.NET` is open-source and the most popular with over 2,000 stars.

Also, check out the official machine learning library for .NET provided by Microsoft: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning

---

**OLD**

There's a neural network library called [AForge.net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge.aspx) on the codeproject. (Code hosted at [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)) (Also checkout the [AForge homepage](http://www.aforgenet.com/) - According to the homepage, the new version now supports genetic algorithms and machine learning as well. It looks like it's progressed a lot since I last played with it)

I don't know it's it's anything like WEKA as I've never used that.

(there's also an article on it's [usage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge_neuro.aspx))

Comment: Not bad though at least for someone not very familiar with the topic it really isn't that good a choice. They don't use partial classes for their forms (makes it hard to read the code behind their samples), and i can't find decent documentation for it.

Comment: @RCIX: I agree it's not exactly simple, you really need to understand neural networks and the maths behind them first. It's certainly not designed to teach NNs but rather to implement them when you know what you are doing. The docs are here - http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/, but yes, they do look a bit sparse. Personally, I haven't used it for several years, and it does look like it's added a lot since then so it's probably grown in complexity.

Comment: AForge is now merged into https://github.com/accord-net/framework

Answer (score 16):

You can also [use Weka with C#](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+with+the+Microsoft+.NET+Framework).  The best solution is to use [**IKVM**, as in this tutorial](http://weka.wikispaces.com/IKVM+with+Weka+tutorial), although you can also use bridging software.

Comment: What "bridging software" are you talking about? which ones?

Answer (score 14):

Weka can be used from C# very easily as Shane stated, using IKVM and some 'glue code'. Folow the tutorial on [weka page](http://weka.wikispaces.com/IKVM+with+Weka+tutorial) to create the '.Net version' of weka, then you can try to run the following tests:

```
[Fact]
public void BuildAndClassify()
{
  var classifier = BuildClassifier();
  AssertCanClassify(classifier);
}

[Fact]
public void DeserializeAndClassify()
{
  BuildClassifier().Serialize("test.weka");
  var classifier = Classifier.Deserialize<LinearRegression>("test.weka");
  AssertCanClassify(classifier);
}

private static void AssertCanClassify(LinearRegression classifier)
{
  var result = classifier.Classify(-402, -1);
  Assert.InRange(result, 255.8d, 255.9d);
}

private static LinearRegression BuildClassifier()
{
  var trainingSet = new TrainingSet("attribute1", "attribute2", "class")
    .AddExample(-173, 3, -31)
    .AddExample(-901, 1, 807)
    .AddExample(-901, 1, 807)
    .AddExample(-94, -2, -86);

  return Classifier.Build<LinearRegression>(trainingSet);
}
```

First test shows, how you build a classifier and classify a new Example with it, the second one shows, how you can use a persisted classifier from a file to classify an example. If you need too support discrete attributes, some modification will be necessery. The code above uses 2 helper classes:

```
public class TrainingSet
{
    private readonly List<string> _attributes = new List<string>();
    private readonly List<List<object>> _examples = new List<List<object>>();

    public TrainingSet(params string[] attributes)
    {
      _attributes.AddRange(attributes);
    }

    public int AttributesCount
    {
      get { return _attributes.Count; }
    }

    public int ExamplesCount
    {
      get { return _examples.Count; }
    }

    public TrainingSet AddExample(params object[] example)
    {
      if (example.Length != _attributes.Count)
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
          String.Format("Invalid number of elements in example. Should be {0}, was {1}.", _attributes.Count,
            _examples.Count));
      }


      _examples.Add(new List<object>(example));

      return this;
    }

    public static implicit operator Instances(TrainingSet trainingSet)
    {
      var attributes = trainingSet._attributes.Select(x => new Attribute(x)).ToArray();
      var featureVector = new FastVector(trainingSet.AttributesCount);

      foreach (var attribute in attributes)
      {
        featureVector.addElement(attribute);
      }

      var instances = new Instances("Rel", featureVector, trainingSet.ExamplesCount);
      instances.setClassIndex(trainingSet.AttributesCount - 1);

      foreach (var example in trainingSet._examples)
      {
        var instance = new Instance(trainingSet.AttributesCount);

        for (var i = 0; i < example.Count; i++)
        {
          instance.setValue(attributes[i], Convert.ToDouble(example[i]));
        }

        instances.add(instance);
      }

      return instances;
    }
}

public static class Classifier
{
    public static TClassifier Build<TClassifier>(TrainingSet trainingSet)
      where TClassifier : weka.classifiers.Classifier, new()
    {
      var classifier = new TClassifier();
      classifier.buildClassifier(trainingSet);
      return classifier;
    }

    public static TClassifier Deserialize<TClassifier>(string filename)
    {
      return (TClassifier)SerializationHelper.read(filename);
    }

    public static void Serialize(this weka.classifiers.Classifier classifier, string filename)
    {
      SerializationHelper.write(filename, classifier);
    }

    public static double Classify(this weka.classifiers.Classifier classifier, params object[] example)
    {
      // instance lenght + 1, because class variable is not included in example
      var instance = new Instance(example.Length + 1);

      for (int i = 0; i < example.Length; i++)
      {
        instance.setValue(i, Convert.ToDouble(example[i]));
      }

      return classifier.classifyInstance(instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I have created an [ML library](http://machine.codeplex.com) in C# that is designed to work with common POCO objects.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a project called Encog that has C# code. It's maintained by Jeff Heaton, the author of an "Introduction to Neural Network" book I bought a while ago. The codebase Git is here: https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core

Answer (score 2):

I'm searching for machine learning libraries for .NET as well and found Infer.NET from Microsoft Research on [nuget.org/machine-learning](http://nuget.org/packages?q=machine-learning):

- [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/infernet/)